# Python: How do I get the right encoding from a file name

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, operating-system, decoding

```
>>> a=os.listdir('.')
>>> a
['arabic??.exe', 'asd.exe', 'chinese??.exe', 'cyrilic??.exe', 'french\xe7\xe9\xfc.exe', 'german\xe4\xdf\xfc.exe', 'registred\xae\xa9.exe', 'sandbox.py', 'spanish\xc1\xcd\xd3.exe']
>>> for each in a:
...  os.system(os.getcwd()+'\\'+each)
...
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I'm trying to open some files with weird characters but the code above works just for the Latin languages. What can I do to get the correct encoding for all the files and to properly open them? or if there is a workaround for this?

Side note that the above logic works well on linux systems.

Filenames:
cyrilicЧБ;chinese伊艾;frenchçéü;arabicشص; spanishÁÍÓ.exe;registred®©.exe;germanäßü.exe

Answer (score 0):

Works if you pass the directory path as a Unicode string, e.g.:

```
os.listdir(u'.')
```

---

**Edit #0:**

You also need to add the following header to your Python script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

You can read more about this here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: it gives me this error when I pass it as unicode:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 41-42: ordinal not in range(128)

If I leave it as byte at least it passes the arguments to the os.system

Comment: Did you specify the encoding for your Python script file? Please check the updated answer.

Comment: yes, I tried with the coding line, also tried to encode the names with .encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding() but it makes no visible difference and I'm kind of stuck here, thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: That is very strange. I get the same output as you if I use the filenames and code that were part of the question. But specifying the path as Unicode and adding the file header resolves this issue. By the way, which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Can you share the output of  sys.stdout.encoding and  sys.stdin.encoding?

Comment: >>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'mbcs'
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'cp437'
Im using win10 and Python 2.7.14

Comment: if I run it from editor, the sys.stdin.encoding is utf-8